# object.width() returns 0

Tags: jquery

I've got the following code:

```
$("#text").css({width: $("#bobby_profiel_img").width()});   
$("#slider").css({width: $("#text").width()});
alert("slider: " + $("#slider").width());   
alert("text: " + $("#text").width());
```

both being called in `$(window).load(function() {}`

But, slider: alerts 0, and text: alerts 960. I'm really stuck here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reverse the order of setting the CSS properties? Also, 'profiel' looks like a typo.

Comment: What does your *actual* code look like?  If you're messing up the line order when posting it, that tells me you're messing with it a great deal, meaning you're probably not posting the *actual* problem. Post the *actual* code.

Comment: Well, yeah, I could post the whole code, but it's really much and really ulgy.

Comment: The weird thing is that typing `$('#slider');` into the Chrome Web Inspector console returns "<div id=​"slider" style=​"width:​ 505px;​ ">​…​</div>", so it seems to *have* a width defined. Although its descendant elements do have their widths set to '0', which might be part of the problem.

Comment: @david , is it a timing issue ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For updated question:*
You're getting `0` because `#slider` isn't visible, so it has a `0` width dimension, it's hidden **by a parent**, so the momentary showing it, getting the width and hiding it that works on `#text` (jQuery does this internally) doesn't work here.  It's hidden by `#text` and `#middle_gallery` parents both having `display: none;`.

The width is being correctly set, it's just the getter that's off here, because of it being hidden.

---

*For original question:*
You're setting the widths (at least seemingly) in the wrong order, it seems like it should be:

```
$("#text").css({width: $("#bobby_profiel_img").width()}); 
$("#slider").css({width: $("#text").width()});
```

The problem is that `#slider` is having it's width set to `#text`'s width before it's set to what it should be, if they're supposed to match - it seems like both should match, or a single statement like this:

```
$("#text, #slider").width($("#bobby_profiel_img").width());
```

Comment: I updated my post, because I typed my two objects in the wrong order. I actually declared them in the right order (first text, than slider).

Comment: @Sammy - You need to post your *actual* code, if you're mucking with it when posting the question there's no telling what other errors you're introducing or leaving out...I'm willing to bet your actual code is much different than what's not in the question.

Comment: @Sammy - The reason it's `0` is the element is hidden, by several parents, I'll update to include this.

Comment: Oke so, when I alert the width it displays 0 and that's because it's display is hidden, but, can I make calculations with it? Because apart from the alert: slider = 0, the slider does not have the right dimensions. Can I only change the slider's width when it's display is visible?

Comment: @Sammy - you can *change* it whenever, it's setting a CSS property that stays, but expect it to be `0` when reading it.

Comment: Hmm, oke. Then the mistake must be somewhere else. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

@sammy

we were discussing the same problem at the other thread , if you are using images and its not ready using

```
$(window).load(function(){  
//initialize after images are loaded  
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
//code here  
});
```

the link explains
http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/

Comment: Thanks. I'd checked out that link before, but, as far as I can see, I'm doing it right. Putting the code in window.load?